Proper Way to Clear all 'Option' Variables for a Function?
I've poked around and searched a bit, but thus far have not been able to find anything that solves the following problem:
ClearAll[HandleRefToRef, csvFile];
Options[HandleRefToRef] = {debugOn -> False, displayImportedData -> False, displayFilteredData -> False};
HandleRefToRef[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
   {functionName = HandleRefToRef, importedData, filteredData, headerRow},
   (* function body *)
   ];

Even if I call ClearAll after I'm done with the function HandleRefToRef, all of the variables (rules?) I passed to Options[HandleRefToRef] still show up if I execute:
?"Global`*"

Is there a way to not only clear the definition of a function, but all of its 'option' rules that were passed to Options?
Thank you.

I suggest using string for option keys, so that there is no need for symbol management. The problem here is that the symbols reserved for options could be used by other functions - they are not bound to this function only, and once you remove them, the other functions will be broken.

To remove the symbol option keys, you can use e.g. clearOptionKey[fun_]:=Remove@Cases[_Symbol]@Keys@Options@fun.

Thanks @Lacia. On your first suggestion, converting the option keys to be strings had the effect that when I attempted to get the value via e.g., OptionValue["debugOn"], I got the error ""Option name !("debugOn") not found in defaults""

Have you convert the ones in Options[...]=... and spell them correctly in the function body?

The string keys are indeed inconvenient for coding, but they are more safe.

I think this is one of those non-problems.  If you call ClearAll[HandleRefToRef] that is all you have to do. The fact that the symbols still exist in the symbol table is inconsequential.

@Lacia, you are correct: the string key version does work. Not sure what happened, but I restarted the kernel and it worked. Would you be able to point me to a reference that discusses the advantages of strings over symbols as keys? I wasn't able to find anything on the Options help page on the Wolfram website.

@JasonB. I obtained the potentially bad habit of (especially when trying to develop new functionality) trying to keep my variable space as clean as possible, for I have found that if I don't do that, it seems that definitions for variables are 'sticky' when I don't want them to be, so I'm left with either restarting the kernel regularly or removing/clearing variables and then validating with ?"Global*"`.

Using string keys for key-value pairs is quite standard in other languages. In MMA there is no "official" or "documented" choice for string vs. symbol keys, but you can check that in recent versions, string keys are more preferred. The only drawback is that by now there is no documented and robust method for autocompletion of string keys.

I personally suggest that, if your codes are not too long and there is no need of maintenance, then both are ok. But when you write long codes like the situation there are several paclets depending on others, then naturally the question appears: which symbol key belongs to which context? You need to manage these symbols by yourself.

If you're really desperate to do things this way (use symbols as option keys and remove them together with f), you could do this:
ClearAll[f]
Options[f] = {option1 -> "1"};
f[OptionsPattern[]] := OptionValue[option1];

f /: Remove[f] := With[{
  opts = Cases[Keys @ Options[f], s_Symbol /; Context[s] =!= "System`"]
},
  Block[{f},
   Remove @@ opts;
   Remove[f]
   ]
  ]

This will make sure that Remove[f] also removes all associated symbols in the option keys.
Edit
I updated the code to exclude System symbols for safety. Most of those should be protected anyway, but it's better to be sure. See also this answer for more discussion about the general perils of Remove.

I feel the OP ought to be warned that removing system symbols, and global symbols in use by other functions, might cause problems.

@sjoerd-smit, thanks I'll give that a whirl, but per michael-e2's comment, I'm wondering if my constant scrubbing of variables is the reason behind why I get strange error popups in the front end? Hmm.

Options have to be removed explicetly
    Options[HandleRefToRef] = {}
    Clear[HandleRefToRef]
    ?HandleRefToRef
    
       Symbol   
         Global`HandleRefToRef  
       Full Name    Global`HandleRefToRef   

Remove clears the symbol list and the Option setting, too.
    Remove[HandleRefToRef]
    
    ?HandleRefToRef
    
      Missing["UnknownSymbol", "HandleRefToRef"]
 


Thanks @roland-f. In the second half where you state "clears the symbol list and the Option setting too," are you saying that Remove will obviate the need to set Options[symbol] to an empty list, or that both are always required, and Remove will only 'remove' the symbol from Options if it has already been set to an empty list?
